# Is there a library or has anyone implemented apple photos pinch to change grid column numbers in iOS

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uipinchgesturerecognizer, pinch, uicollectionviewflowlayout

In the photos app when you pinch on the grid, the number of column changes accordingly and also the cells update when pinch is in progress. It also allows to zoom into grid at any part of the grid. Does anyone know how to achieve this kind of animation or any libraries which can provide this effect in iOS?